# Why is there a NOP in void functions in unoptimized GCC output?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, compiler-optimization, no-op

I'm toying around with executables/compilers/assembly - the whole lot.

```c
void foo(void){
}
```

In the compiler-generated asm, I happened to notice there was a no-op between the function prologue and epilogue ([Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:5,endLineNumber:11,positionColumn:5,positionLineNumber:11,selectionStartColumn:5,selectionStartLineNumber:11,startColumn:5,startLineNumber:11),source:%27void+foo(void)%7B%0A++++%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+bar(int+x)%7B%0A++++return+x%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+sink%3B%0Avoid+baz()%7B%0A++++sink+%3D+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main(void)%7B%0A++++//return+0%3B++//+-std%3Dgnu89+to+not+implicitly+return+0%3B++produces+a+nop+with+GCC11%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:37.174341096871665,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cg494,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dgnu99%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+4.9.4+(C,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.19091413750176,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cg112,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:7,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:7,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.2+(C,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:29.634744765626568,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)):

```
foo:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        nop                      ## <--- this line
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

I compiled it with `gcc -S` (no optimisations); it's gone when compiling with `-O1`, so my theory is that it's for debugging.

However I'm not clear on its purpose. Even for debugging, having a no-op - by definition - makes **no difference** to how the program behaves, whatsoever.

So why is there?

---

##### Further results

- The NOP is new in GCC5; not present in GCC4.9.4
- The NOP is gone in any function that actually returns a value.  (Falling off the end of an `int` function still produces a `nop`, including for `main` in C89 mode without implicit return 0).

```
int bar(int x){
    return x;
}
```

```
bar:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

- Having a non-empty function body isn't what avoids the NOP:

```
int sink;
void baz(){
    sink = 0;
}
```

```
baz:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR sink[rip], 0
        nop                       ## <--- Still present
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

```
int main(void){
    //return 0;  // -std=gnu89 to not implicitly return 0;  produces a nop
}
```

```
# GCC11 defaults to -std=gnu17  so return 0 is implicit
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     eax, 0         # replaced with a NOP with -std=gnu89
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Comment: I don't know exactly why; it doesn't make any sense to me any previous time I've wondered what part of the `gcc -O0` internals produce an actual nop.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: `0xa` is 10, `0xb`  is 11; it's *definitely* not for alignment because it's making the address odd, when it was previously aligned by 2.

Comment: Exactly. If it were there for alignment, then that would completely defeat its own purpose

Comment: Why did you choose a broken program as your example, instead of an empty `main` or an empty `void foo(void){}`?  You can't `ret` from `_start` (RSP points at `argc`, not a return address, in the x86-64 SysV ABI) so this will crash if you build that way and run it.  It's also not safe in general to use write any registers in a GNU C Basic Asm statement (without declaring a clobber on `"edx"`).  These things kind of detract from the question, which could use a much simpler example without any weird stuff like `asm()`.  e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/6Y1jxvG1j.  (You can still edit to simplify.)

Comment: BTW, this `nop` first appeared in GCC5.0, as a "regression" from GCC4.9.  Perhaps it's intentional as a place to set a breakpoint on, IDK.

Comment: @PeterCordes The program is deliberately not functional as any code needed to make it so adds to the complexity. My actual use case for it is to see what the binary output of a `movl` instruction is in GCC, so functionality is unnecessary in my case

Comment: Your breakpoint point is a good one though :/

Comment: You can get that by disassembling a `.o`, and more simply you could have put it in a `.s` file instead of wrapping a C program around it.  Anyway, I guess that's the context in which you noticed this `nop`, but a better [mcve] for your SO question about the NOP would have simplified it down to `void foo(void){}`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll keep them in mind for next time

Comment: Re “having a noop - by definition - makes no difference to how the program behaves, whatsoever”: That is not the definition of a no-op. It performs no computation **except** an increment of the program counter, and it can affect execution time. It occupies space in memory and is sometimes used for alignment reasons and otherwise as a filler.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Would the phrase _not do anything impactful_ be more accurate?

Comment: This is an interesting question about GCC's design decision(?) or different internals that produces this, so I went ahead and replaced your [mcve] with better ones.  (Including discovering that it seems to be lack of a return value that seems to be the cause, so that suggests it's leftover internal stuff that's not getting optimized away with optimization disabled.)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts in making the question more on-point. Your examples are indeed more reflective of the underlying question.

Comment: An accurate definition of a NOP might be "an instruction that has no effect on the *architectural state*, other than incrementing the program counter".  What your question currently says seems reasonable enough to me, though; you're not trying to give a full definition of a NOP, and it's clearish from context that you mean no effect on correctness. (And that does follow directly from the actual definition.) @Eric's nitpick seems pretty minor since GCC `-O0` pretty clearly isn't doing this for alignment or performance.  Although it is technically correct.

Comment: Re “Would the phrase *not do anything impactful* be more accurate?”: No, because this question is about what the impact of a no-op instruction is. Unless GCC’s generation of a no-op is completely the result of some error in its code generation code, there was some effect of the no-op that resulted in it being generated. You do not want to dismiss the possibility it has some reason for existence until we figure out whether it does or not. And it is not a nit-pick; I have seen no-ops used to create desired alignment for critical performance reasons. They have real, sometimes valuable effects.

Comment: (Also, on the Digital Alpha, a no-op could be needed in a branch-delay slot. The Alpha had branch instructions that executed a branch after one more instruction was executed, as a way of giving the processor advance notice that a branch was coming. Usually, of course, you would put a useful instruction in the branch-delay slot, but that was not always possible, so sometimes you needed a no-op.)

Comment: Re "No": How would you rephrase that point? Something like what you mentioend: _The noop does nothing except increment the program counter_?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: DEC Alpha AXP didn't have branch delay slots  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEC_Alpha#Design_principles); the ISA was aimed at high-performance superscalar implementations right from the start, so a branch delay slot would be more hindrance than help; branch prediction was needed to hide branch latency.  Perhaps you're thinking of MIPS, the most well-known classic RISC to use branch delay slots?  It was designed 10 years earlier, aimed at a scalar implementation, where being pipelined in more than just prefetch was the new innovation enabled by RISC.  NOP is important there

Comment: @EricPostpischil: This is an x86 question; there's never a need for a NOP for correctness.  Except maybe in terms of debugging experience, giving an actual machine-code address separate from the epilogue to set a breakpoint on.  But for some reason GCC `-O0` still emits a NOP in non-empty functions with no return value, so IDK.  I didn't check GCC output for other ISAs; that's a good idea, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yes, it was MIPS. And of course this is not applicable to x86; that is why the entire comment is in parentheses. It is supplementary information for people who are interested.

Comment: Which I was, I might add.